# Error One hot Encoding with both type object and string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to one hot encode 2 variables that I have in my dataframe it works for the first one but not the second. Both are of type object. I have tried converting both to strings but that also gave me an error. Error message is: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
[with type string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLMbD.png)
[with type object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gopcn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have overwritten your `df` by `df = ohe.fit_transform(...)`, just name the variable something else. Try this:

```
var1 = ohe.fit_transform(df[["HvacMode"]])
var2 = ohe.fit_transform(df[["Schedule"]])
```

Comment: But the column that I am encoding is different. Or does it not matter?

Comment: Let me clarify:  the `df = ohe.fit_transform(df[["HvacMode"]])` line is overwriting your actual df, so when you call `df = ohe.fit_transform(df[["Schedule"]])`  the `df` in `df[["Schedule"]]` is the OHE of the `df[["HvacMode"]]`, and not the original df, makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. Thanks for the help